# PHP generate list of file on other server

Tags: php, audio

Maybe this isn't even possible, but I'm open for suggestions.

My audio files are located on `//server1/media/music/`.
My apache is on `//server2/apache`.

Now I need to tell my PHP application on `server2` to generate a list from `server1`'s audio files.

Where do I start?

Comment: You could make an API for this, send back a json from server1 when called with some credentials(security, optional depending on your use case)

Comment: well, if you mount the folder as network share, you can just scan it like any regular folder. or you could let server1 generate the list and sync it to server2.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using part of Franz Gleichmann's suggestion.
But instead of mounting the remote drive (which I tried at first), I simply had `scandir("//server1/media/music/")` generate an array for me. And I got the result I wanted.